# Apple Rejection - We noticed that your app did not run at iPhone resolution when reviewed on iPad running iOS 8.1.3,

Tags: ios, iphone

We have built an App which was initially supporting iPhone . 1st Build apple approved with out any issue.

Next build apple rejected saying  We noticed that your app did not run at iPhone resolution. Even though it was not a universal app

We have now made ipad storyboard and tested in all ipads and we could see all menus are appearing properly . Now we got an error saying "We noticed that your app did not run at iPhone resolution when reviewed on iPad running iOS 8.1.3"

I could see that screenshots attached are iPhone sizes and our Menu's are cut . How to reproduce this. How can we run an app on  ipad with IPhone resolution and most important how can we fix it

Comment: Did you make you app a Universal app?  You should *either* make it a universal app with an iPad storyboard (or use size classes with a single storyboard) *or* make it iPhone only with a single iPhone storyboard but make sure that it runs  & displays correctly on an iPad (i.e. iPhone size in the middle of the screen or full screen at 2x resolution)

Comment: its Universal App-with 2 story boards. When I run on ipad it works fine .It was built using xcode 5 . The issue is on Iphone resolution on ipad . How do we test that. We ported to xcode 6 and when we use Resizable ipad in simulator and when we give 640*960 - we could see that our screens are getting cut . How do we resolve this ? Are we going right direction?

Comment: If you have a universal app with native support for iPad then you no longer have to worry about iPhone resolution on iPad - that is only for iPhone only apps.

Comment: Paul thanks..Do you know where is this mentioned in review guidelines?

Comment: Section 2.10 - "iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution."  A universal app is not an iPhone app, so 2.10 doesn't apply

Comment: Thanks Paul- I will go for an appeal and wait for the response